# How to make a symbol between letters bold in flex spark

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I had a code like this

```
var str:string = "GeoCode: 3";
```

in this code I want ":" to be in bold.

How can I do that and this should be done in spark

Please help me

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use [TextFlowUtil.importFromString()](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/utils/TextFlowUtil.html#importFromString%28%29) and assign the resulting [TextFlow](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html) object to a [RichText](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/RichText.html) component, like this:

```
<s:RichText id="textDisplay"/>

textDisplay.textFlow = 
   TextFlowUtil.importFromString('GeoCode<span fontWeight="bold">:</span> 3');
```

If you'd like to keep your original Strings intact, you can do a replace on them to add the span:

```
var str:String = "GeoCode: 3";
str = str.replace(/:/, '<span fontWeight="bold">:</span>');
textDisplay.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

[image]

The text property of the component is splitted into parts by means of ":" symbol. Then each part is added into a HGroup like a Label. Colons are added bold.

//Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:com="com.*">

<s:VGroup left="20" top="20">
    <com:GeoLabel text="GeoCode: 3"/>
    <com:GeoLabel text="GeoCode: 5: Some Info: 123"/>
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

//GeoLabel component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
      width="120" height="25" gap="0">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.Label;
        private var _text:String;

        public function get text():String
        {
            return _text;
        }

        public function set text(value:String):void
        {
            _text = value;

            createMembers();
        }

        private function insertLabel(str:String, bold:Boolean):void
        {
            var la:Label = new Label();
            la.text = str;

            if (bold)
                la.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");

            this.addElement(la);
        }

        private function createMembers():void
        {
            this.removeAllElements();

            var arr:Array = text.split(":");

            for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                    insertLabel(":", true);
                insertLabel(arr[i], false);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:HGroup>
```